Sticky header and footer with Next.js
I used React pretty extensively before but I am very new to Next.js and the layout logic doesn't make much sense to me. From what I understand if layout.js is under /app that means that layout applies to the entire application which is exactly what I want. Now, I want to have a header and a footer. Footer should stick to the bottom of the page and header should stick to the top and not be hidden when I scroll. I was able to achieve that by putting my components in page.js but once I started using routing I realized that's not the right spot for them and according to the docs they should be in layout.js instead:
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import FooterComponent from "@/app/components/footer/footer.component";
import HeaderComponent from "@/app/components/header/header.component";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Solute Art Studio",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
      <html lang="en">
          <body>
            <HeaderComponent/>
            <main>{children}</main>
            <FooterComponent/>
          </body>
      </html>
  );
}

Once I moved them there I broke header's stickiness, it disappears when I scroll now. And the footer is still at the bottom but even if there is nothing in between the header and the footer I have to scroll to it. I feel like I broke some CSS after I moved these components to layout.js. What am I doing wrong? I am using tailwind. Header: <Disclosure as="nav" className="bg-white shadow sticky top-0">.... Footer: <footer className="bg-white sticky top-[100vh]">...

make footer sticky top 100vh minus height of footer somehow, not top-[100vh], I am not familiar with tailwind, but you got the logic.

The best way to do this is to wrap your header, footer, and children (the page) in a div that is set to "h-screen", then using flex-grow around your children as in the following code:
<div className="flex flex-col h-screen w-screen">
  <Header />
    <div className="flex flex-grow flex-row max-w-full max-h-full overflow-auto">
      {children}
    </div>
  <Footer />
</div>

Putting the Header and Footer in the layout will apply them to all pages. With the page content (children) wrapped in a div with "flex-grow", it will fill the space between them, and the overflow-auto will give you a scroll if the page content is larger than the view height, while keeping your header and footer at the top and bottom of the page.
